# Chronicle-map update persisted value

Tags: dictionary, persist, chronicle, chronicle-map

I need to update a persisted value.
I mean:

////// Class InfoEquipoCache used as value of CM

```
class InfoEquipoCache implements BytesMarshallable {
    private EquipoCache equipoCache;
    public void actualiza() {
        .....
        equipoCache.actualiza()
        ......
    }
    .......
```

///// Principal Class has a CM of InfoEquipoCache

```
ChronicleMap<String, InfoEquipoCache> equipos;
```

.....
//// In some part of principal class:

```
equipos.get(idEquipo).actualiza() //InfoEquipoCache contains actualiza method
```

But, equipos.get(idEquipo) has a reference of EquipoCache and inside InfoEquipoCache has a diferent reference of EquipoCache. As results actualiza method is usseless

Someone knows how to make changes of this value?

Answer (score 1):

When you store a value in Chronicle Map, it is serialised to off-heap memory; therefore when you call `get()` you will be retrieving a different (albeit *value-equal*) instance.

If you need to work with the same instance, then you should consider an in-memory solution (e.g. `j.u.HashMap` or `j.u.c.ConcurrentHashMap`).

Answer (score 0):

You could store and update EquipoCache value off-heap inside the Chronicle Map.
Don't forget to write value back to CM at the end of manupulations.

```
try (ExternalMapQueryContext<String, InfoEquipoCache, ?> ctx = map.queryContext(idEquipo)) {
    ctx.updateLock().lock();
    try {
        MapEntry<String, InfoEquipoCache> entry = ctx.entry();
        if (entry != null) {
            InfoEquipoCache infoEquipoCache = entry.value().get();
            infoEquipoCache.actualiza();
            ctx.replaceValue(entry,ctx.wrapValueAsData(infoEquipoCache));
        }
    } finally {
        ctx.readLock().unlock();  //release all-type locks
    }
}
```

Also you can read this in a Chronicle Map [tutorial](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/ea/docs/CM_Tutorial.adoc)